# SurrealDB - How to add trigger function to run when a table changed?

Tags: surrealdb

I'm looking to create a function that activates whenever there's a change in a table.

The primary objective is to maintain and update the `latest timestamp` whenever any modification occurs in the table, similar to how a "Last Updated" status is tracked in files.

How can I connect a function to run on changes in a specific table?